# SFINAE return type overload

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I am trying to have two overloads of same function called something. This function should take another function as parameter, and it should be overload based on return type of this other function. So far I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

unsigned long function1() {
    return 5;
}
void function2() {
    return;
}

template <typename Algorithm, typename enable_if<is_void<decltype(Algorithm())>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void something(Algorithm a) {
    std::cout << "algorithm returns void\n";
}
template <typename Algorithm, typename enable_if<!is_void<decltype(Algorithm())>::value>::type* = nullptr>
decltype(Algorithm()) something(Algorithm a) {
    std::cout << "algorithm returns non-void: " << a() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    something(function1);
    something(function2);
}
```

However, this does not compile. Here is build message I get with gcc compiler:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Library (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp||In instantiation of 'decltype (Algorithm()) something(Algorithm) [with Algorithm = long unsigned int (*)(); typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_void<decltype (Algorithm())>::value), void>::type* <anonymous> = 0u; decltype (Algorithm()) = long unsigned int (*)()]':|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|23|required from here|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|20|warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp||In instantiation of 'decltype (Algorithm()) something(Algorithm) [with Algorithm = void (*)(); typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_void<decltype (Algorithm())>::value), void>::type* <anonymous> = 0u; decltype (Algorithm()) = void (*)()]':|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|24|required from here|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >((* & std::cout), ((const char*)"algorithm returns non-void: ")) << a()'|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|note: candidates are:|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|106|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|106|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&) {aka std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)}'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|115|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|115|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type&) {aka std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)}'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|125|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|125|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|164|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|164|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'long int'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|168|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|168|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'long unsigned int'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|172|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|172|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'bool'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\ostream.tcc|93|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\ostream.tcc|93|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'short int'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|179|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|179|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'short unsigned int'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\ostream.tcc|107|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\ostream.tcc|107|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'int'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|190|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|190|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'unsigned int'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|199|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|199|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'long long int'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|203|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|203|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'long long unsigned int'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|218|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|218|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'double'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|222|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|222|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'float'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|230|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|230|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'long double'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|243|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|243|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'const void*'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\ostream.tcc|121|note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\ostream.tcc|121|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<char>*}'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2750|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2750|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|note:   mismatched types 'const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>' and 'void'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|469|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|469|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_CharT' ('char' and 'void')|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|474|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, char)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|474|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|note:   cannot convert 'a()' (type 'void') to type 'char'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|480|note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, char)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|480|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|note:   cannot convert 'a()' (type 'void') to type 'char'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|486|note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, signed char)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|486|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|note:   cannot convert 'a()' (type 'void') to type 'signed char'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|491|note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|491|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|note:   cannot convert 'a()' (type 'void') to type 'unsigned char'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|511|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const _CharT*)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|511|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|note:   mismatched types 'const _CharT*' and 'void'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\ostream.tcc|323|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const char*)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\ostream.tcc|323|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|note:   cannot convert 'a()' (type 'void') to type 'const char*'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|528|note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const char*)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|528|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|note:   cannot convert 'a()' (type 'void') to type 'const char*'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|541|note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const signed char*)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|541|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|note:   cannot convert 'a()' (type 'void') to type 'const signed char*'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|546|note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const unsigned char*)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|546|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|note:   cannot convert 'a()' (type 'void') to type 'const unsigned char*'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|600|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Tp> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|600|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|19|required from 'decltype (Algorithm()) something(Algorithm) [with Algorithm = void (*)(); typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_void<decltype (Algorithm())>::value), void>::type* <anonymous> = 0u; decltype (Algorithm()) = void (*)()]'|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|24|required from here|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|600|error: forming reference to void|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp||In instantiation of 'decltype (Algorithm()) something(Algorithm) [with Algorithm = void (*)(); typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_void<decltype (Algorithm())>::value), void>::type* <anonymous> = 0u; decltype (Algorithm()) = void (*)()]':|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|24|required from here|
C:\Alex\Programming\C++\Library\test.cpp|20|warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 10 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

Is what I am trying to achieve possible in c++? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

`Algorithm` doesn't call the function but create an instance of the deduced type of the function. You need another pair of parentheses in order to call it

```
decltype(Algorithm()())
```

or even:

```
std::declval<Algorithm>()()
```

if your type is a functor with an inaccessible default-constructor.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that you can instantiate normal function this way.

Comment: Can you provide a compilable code using this approach, provided that `Algorithm` is a function type?

Comment: or `auto something(Algorithm a) -> decltype(a())`.